# How to move several .txt files into folders according to their names in PHP?

Tags: php, copy, strpos, unlink

I have a folder that contains 3 subfolders and .txt files named like this :

[image]

I would like :

- If the file starts with A500 it should be moved to the subfolder FR
- If the file starts with A700 it is moved to the ES subfolder.
- If the file starts with A900 it is moved to the PT subfolder.

I've done this function, but it's not working... Where's my mistake?

```
<?php

function deplacementFile( $path ) {

   $dir    = './test/';
   $allFiles = scandir($dir);

   foreach($allFiles as $file) {

        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..","FR", "ES", "PT")))
      { 

      $file = $dir.$file;
      $filename = basename( $file );

       //read the entire string
       $str = file_get_contents( $file );

       if ( strpos( $filename, 'A500_' ) === 0 ) {
        $dossierDestination1 = './test/FR/';
        if(!copy($dir, $dossierDestination1)) { 
            echo "error copy";
            } else { 
            if(!unlink($dir)) { 
                echo "error unlink"; 
            } 
        }
      }
        else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A700_' ) === 0 ) {
            $dossierDestination2 = './test/ES/';
            if(!copy($dir, $dossierDestination2)) { 
                echo "error copy";
                } else { 
                if(!unlink($dir)) { 
                    echo "error unlink"; 
                } 
            }
          }

       else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A900_' ) === 0 ) {
        $dossierDestination3 = './test/PT/';
        if(!copy($dir, $dossierDestination3)) { 
            echo "error copy";
            } else { 
            if(!unlink($dir)) { 
                echo "error unlink"; 
            } 
        }
      }
            else {

           return false;
       }
    }
  }
}

deplacementFile( './test/' ); 

echo "Successfully completed!";
?>
```

Comment: `copy($dir`? Mustn't you `$copy(FILE`?

Comment: If I replace $dir with $file I have: Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in

Comment: So instead of directory - provide filename in this directory, no?

Comment: But I have to scan my entire folder, so I can't give him a file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a upgraded version of your script:

```
function deplacementFile( $path ) {

    $dir    = './test/';
    $allFiles = scandir($dir);

    foreach($allFiles as $file) {
        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..","FR", "ES", "PT")))
        { 
            // $file - is PATH to copied file
            $file = $dir.$file;
            // $filename - is the name of file being copied
            $filename = basename( $file );

            $paths = [
                'A500_' => './test/FR/',
                'A700_' => './test/ES/',
                'A900_' => './test/PT/',
            ];
            foreach ($paths as $key => $dest) {
                if (strpos( $filename, $key ) === 0) {
                    // copy from PATH to new path which is `dest and filename`
                    if(!copy($file, $dest . $filename)) { 
                        echo "error copy";
                    } else { 
                        if(!unlink($file)) { 
                            echo "error unlink"; 
                        } 
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider [`rename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) which **moves** file, the arguments are the same, but you don't need `unlink`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and your script! When I execute it I get an error : Warning: copy(./test/FR/./test/A500_2.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in at the line "if(!copy($file, $dest . $file)) { ".

Comment: Check the arguments: `$file` and `$dest . $file` right before copying.

Comment: I made a var_dump($dest.$file); and I get : './test/FR/./test/A500_2.txt'. I think it's because the path he wants to copy the files to is not good.

Comment: My mistake - `$dest . $filename`, as `$file` is a path already.